# Is there a way to align or manipulate the position of a QIcon inside a QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Intro: I am using PySide and the Qt Framework to build a GUI app

I am dynamically adding `edit` and `delete` icons in a QTableWidgetItem and I am trying to align them in the center of the cell. I have tried setTextAlign and setStyleSheet on various parts of the QTableWidget.

If anyone knows a workaround that would be awesome.

I am also wanting these to be clickable so that if the user clicks the `edit` they will be able to edit the corresponding object that row applies to. If someone could help me out with this as well that would be even more awesome.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably end up using [QTableWidget::setCellWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget)

You'd be able to create your own custom widget, in this case you might try creating a `QToolButton` centered inside of a `QFrame` in designer and then set that as the widget for the cells in your table that you want it to appear in.

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow. Thank you.
Edit: I think this is a better way: [LINK](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget). That way I can still use QTableWidget and not QTreeWidget

Comment: Ah yes, I got those two functions mixed up.