# Setting the size of an SVG icon in a table cell

Tags: user-interface, pyside, qtgui

I'd like to increase the size of an SVG icon that's displayed inside of a PySide/Qt table cell

```
    icon = QtGui.QIcon('icon.svg')
    entry = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    entry.setIcon(icon)
    entry.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    table.setItem(row_index, column_index, entry)
```

Absolutely nothing I try increases the size of the displayed SVG. It is currently displayed as a very small icon and also seems to ignore the alignment. The [QIcon](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QIcon.pixmap) docs say that items can be scaled, so there must be a way.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `table.setIconSize(QSize(w, h)` (if you use `QTableWidget`) and `entry.setSizeHint(QSize(w, h)`, docs [here](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidgetItem.html?highlight=setsizehint#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.setSizeHint), like so:

```
table.setIconSize(QSize(50, 50))
icon = QtGui.QIcon('icon.svg')
entry = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
entry.setSizeHint(QSize(50, 50))
entry.setIcon(icon)
entry.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
table.setItem(row_index, column_index, entry)
```

The alignment cannot be changed I'm afraid (maybe is doable customizing `QTableWidget` class). If alignment is a must maybe you can use `QTableWidget.setCellWidget()`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463016/is-there-a-way-to-align-or-manipulate-the-position-of-a-qicon-inside-a-qtablewid) answer.

Comment: Thanks! Any way to control the size of the icon individually, rather than define a global size for the entire table?

Comment: Interestingly, this also doesn't affect icons in the header. Any suggestion for dealing with that?